# Border on Google Chrome. (CSS) ¿How to remove?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My page shows a border than i do not put it (sorry for my english);

[Google Chrome](http://gyazo.com/3a8b7bdf27b88fe70ed7b2eefe5b45a0) [IMAGE]

[Internet Explorer +10](http://gyazo.com/9f7e844008b268184d1c487033ae0e30) [IMAGE]

This is my css code

```
#mydiv {
    width:98px;
    height:98px;
    border-radius: 52%;
    border:solid 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
    left:85%;
}
#mydiv img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 52%;
    border:solid 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: If the image is a link, try something like. a img { border: none;}. You should also show the html and CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Copy and replace the your code with the follow one:

```
#mydiv {
width:98px;
height:98px;
border-radius: 52%;
border:none;
position:absolute;
top:-50px;
left:85%;
}
#mydiv img {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius: 52%;
border:none;
z-index: -1;
}
```

It will fix your problem amigo.

You can also just delete the border

Comment: Ya lo hice y el problema sigue... Pero solo es en google Chrome

Comment: Sleek Geek has the solution. It must be the link image border set it to 0